# Why does a UnicastProcessor plus ConnectableFlux send previously emitted items downstream on autoConnect but not on connect()

Tags: spring, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I have this upstream Publisher that emits a number every second:

```
private fun counter(emissionIntervalMillis: Long) =
        Flux.interval(Duration.ofMillis(emissionIntervalMillis))
                .map { it }.log()
```

Consider this implementation in which a `UnicastProcessor` subscribes to the previous `Flux`. In addition there is a `ConnectableFlux` generated with `processor.publish().autoConnect()`. Finally I subscribe to this `ConnectableFlux`:

```
    val latch = CountDownLatch(15)

    val numberGenerator: Flux<Long> = counter(1000)
    val processor = UnicastProcessor.create<Long>()
    numberGenerator.subscribeWith(processor)
    val connectableFlux = processor.doOnSubscribe { println("subscribed!") }.publish().autoConnect()

    Thread.sleep(5000)

    connectableFlux.subscribe {
        logger.info("Element [{}]", it)
        latch.countDown()
    }

    latch.await()
```

Logs:

```
15:58:26.941 [main] DEBUG reactor.util.Loggers$LoggerFactory - Using Slf4j logging framework
15:58:26.967 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.Map.1 - onSubscribe(FluxMap.MapSubscriber)
15:58:26.969 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.Map.1 - request(unbounded)
15:58:27.973 [parallel-1] INFO reactor.Flux.Map.1 - onNext(0)
15:58:28.973 [parallel-1] INFO reactor.Flux.Map.1 - onNext(1)
15:58:29.975 [parallel-1] INFO reactor.Flux.Map.1 - onNext(2)
15:58:30.974 [parallel-1] INFO reactor.Flux.Map.1 - onNext(3)
15:58:31.974 [parallel-1] INFO reactor.Flux.Map.1 - onNext(4)
subscribed!
15:58:31.979 [main] INFO com.codependent.processors.Tests - Element [0]
15:58:31.980 [main] INFO com.codependent.processors.Tests - Element [1]
15:58:31.980 [main] INFO com.codependent.processors.Tests - Element [2]
15:58:31.980 [main] INFO com.codependent.processors.Tests - Element [3]
15:58:31.980 [main] INFO com.codependent.processors.Tests - Element [4]
15:58:32.972 [parallel-1] INFO reactor.Flux.Map.1 - onNext(5)
15:58:32.972 [parallel-1] INFO com.codependent.processors.Tests - Element [5]
```

As you see, when there is a subscriber to the connectableFlux, it gets the previously generated items which were cached by the UnicastProcessor. I guess this is the [expected behaviour](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#_unicastprocessor):

> if you push any amount of data through it while its Subscriber has not
>   yet requested data, it will buffer all of the data.

Now, instead of using `autoConnect` I use `connect()`:

```
    val latch = CountDownLatch(15)

    val numberGenerator: Flux<Long> = counter(1000)
    val processor = UnicastProcessor.create<Long>()
    numberGenerator.subscribeWith(processor)
    val connectableFlux = processor.doOnSubscribe { println("subscribed!") }.publish()
    connectableFlux.connect()

    Thread.sleep(5000)

    connectableFlux.subscribe {
        logger.info("Element [{}]", it)
        latch.countDown()
    }
```

The result now quite different, the subscriber doesn't get the items that should've been cached by the `UnicastProcessor`. Can someone explain the difference?

```
16:08:44.299 [main] DEBUG reactor.util.Loggers$LoggerFactory - Using Slf4j logging framework
16:08:44.324 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.Map.1 - onSubscribe(FluxMap.MapSubscriber)
16:08:44.326 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.Map.1 - request(unbounded)
subscribed!
16:08:45.330 [parallel-1] INFO reactor.Flux.Map.1 - onNext(0)
16:08:46.329 [parallel-1] INFO reactor.Flux.Map.1 - onNext(1)
16:08:47.329 [parallel-1] INFO reactor.Flux.Map.1 - onNext(2)
16:08:48.331 [parallel-1] INFO reactor.Flux.Map.1 - onNext(3)
16:08:49.330 [parallel-1] INFO reactor.Flux.Map.1 - onNext(4)
16:08:50.328 [parallel-1] INFO reactor.Flux.Map.1 - onNext(5)
16:08:50.328 [parallel-1] INFO com.codependent.processors.Tests - Element [5]
16:08:51.332 [parallel-1] INFO reactor.Flux.Map.1 - onNext(6)
16:08:51.332 [parallel-1] INFO com.codependent.processors.Tests - Element [6]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After rereading the docs I found that `autoConnect()` can pass the minimum number of subscribers necessary to subscribe to the upstream. Changing it to `autoConnect(0)` has the same effect as `connect()`, not passing the previous items to the subscriber:

```
    val latch = CountDownLatch(15)

    val numberGenerator: Flux<Long> = counter(1000)
    val processor = UnicastProcessor.create<Long>()
    numberGenerator.subscribeWith(processor)
    val connectableFlux = processor.doOnSubscribe { println("subscribed!") }.log().publish().autoConnect(0)

    Thread.sleep(5000)

    connectableFlux.subscribe {
        logger.info("Element [{}]", it)
        latch.countDown()
    }

    latch.await()
```

**It seems that since the connectableFlux is ready (connected), the processor gets the OnSubscribe signal, and as there aren't any actual subscribers for the connectableFlux, it discards the items.**

Changing `publish()` to `replay()` would make the subscriber get the items from the beginning , as [stated in the doc](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#advanced-broadcast-multiple-subscribers-connectableflux).

```
val connectableFlux = processor.doOnSubscribe { println("subscribed!") }.log().replay().autoConnect(0)
```

Comment: Yes, and furthermore in your example that uses `connect`, you should subscribe to the `ConnectableFlux` **before** calling `connect()` (the whole point of that method is to give you time to establish multiple downstream subscriptions before _connect_ing to upstream)